# Serilog + SSMS + Winforms doent's write any tabke on my ssms db, why?

Tags: serilog

I have created a .NET Winforms Application in Visual Studio 2022 and i use on it some textboxs and a listbox to select items, and there a table of generic user connected to SSMS and it works correctly.

The problems starts if i want to use Serilog

1 - I Opened the NuGet Manager Packages and installed Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 6.3.0, Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching 3.1.0, Serilog 3.0.1

2 - Then edited constructor of Manager.cs:
public Manager(string cs, string db, string logs)
{
dBUtils = new DBUtils(cs);
nome_db = db;

```
        UsaLogs(cs, logs);
    }

    public static void UsaLogs(string connectionString, string logs_table)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, logs_table)
            .CreateLogger();

        Log.Information("UsaLogs ON");

        try
        {
            int a = 20;
            int b = 0;
            Log.Debug($"{a} / {b}");
            int c = a / b;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Errore UseLogs");
        }

        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
```

And connected it to Form1.cs:

```
    Manager DBManager;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Istanzio un nuovo oggetto manager a cui passo la connection string il nome del db
        DBManager = new Manager("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TaskFormUtenteGenerico;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=formazione;Password=admin", "tbl_Utenti", "Logs");
        DBManager.RechargeAllBoxes(lbAll: listBox_TutteLePersone,txtAll: txtBox_TutteLePersone);
    }
```

3 - I created on my DB Logs table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Logs] (

   [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Message] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [MessageTemplate] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [Level] nvarchar(128) NULL,
   [TimeStamp] datetime NOT NULL,
   [Exception] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [Properties] nvarchar(max) NULL

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

but if i do a SELECT * FROM Logs; after program starts it doesn't show anything, no errors and no loggers

i watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mpvnN1-_rY and this topic: https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver